# OpenCV findContours works only intermittently

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently running a very basic script using drawContours() to outline contours. Unfortunately, this only runs correctly about 1/5 times and I have to manually close and reload the script every time, waiting for findContours to work.

Here's the script and a picture of what I'm doing (when the drawContours script works)

```
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("val", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("val",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while True:
    ret, val = cap.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(val, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cnts,__ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        print("Area: {}".format(area))
        if area > 100:
            cv2.drawContours(val,i,-1, (0,0,255),1)
    cv2.imshow('val', val)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

[Me with contours outlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dabxu.png)

Answer (score 2):

Find contours works best with an edge/binary image, eg cv2.threshold or  cv2.adaptiveThreshold

See [contour tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try thresholding your image:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, 0)
```

and then try to find the countours:

```
cnts,__ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```